# Was the Space Shuttle TPS technology ever state secret?

Tags: space-shuttle, heat-shield, buran

I was a bit surprised to learn that the [Buran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buran_(spacecraft)) used heat tiles looking very similar to that of the Space Shuttle. Considering its potential for military application, and the cold war period in which both the US Space Shuttle and Russian Buran were developed, was any of the heat tile technology ever classified as state secret? If so, how did the Russian space program end up with something so similar? Was any/all of the technology patented (which would account for public disclosure and availability of the necessary information to reproduce it)?

Comment: What potential for military application?  ICBM reentry vehicles have to use thick ablative heatshields - SS/Buran-like tiles would burn up under those sorts of thermal loads, and and turnaround time isn't a factor for something that's only ever going to be used once.

Answer (score 7):

[Apparently](https://www.myplainview.com/news/article/Years-of-Study-Led-to-Space-Shuttle-Tiles-9110954.php) the technology wasn't even patented.

> "Lockheed refused to file a patent, saying there was no market for
>   it," Forsberg said. "It was put on the shelf and his research stopped
>   for two years. Then interest from the shuttle program revived it."

As described in Heppenheimer's [Development of the Space Shuttle, 1972-1981](https://books.google.com/books/about/Development_of_the_Space_Shuttle_1972_19.html?id=NhJ1RAAACAAJ) Chapter 6, Thermal Protection, manufacture of the tiles is fairly simple. (I am sure the devil is in the details though).

A slurry of silica fibers of 1.5 micron diameter mixed with a collodial silica binder is pressed into rectangular molds, dried in a microwave oven, then baked in kilns.  The resulting blocks were then shaped and coated with a reaction-cured glass coating.

(summarized by me)

The manufacture was simple enough that after Orbiter production ceased, replacement tiles were made in a small tile shop at Kennedy Space Center.

[image]

Picture from [Wings in Orbit](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/wingsinorbit/index.html)

Ancedotally, I don't remember any aspect of tile technology being treated as sensitive when I worked in the program.  Detailed information is available in the [Press Kit](https://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/technology/sts-newsref/sts_sys.html#sts-hrsi) which was contemporary with the first launch.

[Source](https://www.ourmidland.com/news/article/Years-of-Study-Led-to-Space-Shuttle-Tiles-7063524.php)

Comment: re: "not even patented" - a patent requires you to disclose what you're patenting, so a patent would have contained a detailed description of how to produce these tiles. Patenting is not something you do for classified processes.

Comment: I know, I included the quote just because I thought it was interesting that LockMart thought it was worthless tech.

Comment: Not filing a patent doesn't necessarily mean they thought it was useless.  Patents have a ticking clock -- they require disclosure, and they expire.  If you don't make any money before the patent expires, then you just gave away your tech for free.  Putting it on the shelf allows them to keep it as a trade secret, until the time is right.  You don't file for a patent on something like this unless a) you think you can use it to make money before it expires, and b) you are worried someone else might patent it first.

Comment: The quote says they thought there was no market for it.

Comment: That sounds rather similar to the fibrous refractory insulation that is used in most recently-built industrial furnaces, except that this insulation is probably denser and definitely alumina-silica rather than just silica.

Comment: OTOH @Hobbes, patenting some can lead to it being classified

Answer (score 1):

Even though it occasionally launched military satellites from the Shuttle, NASA is explicitly civilian, created during the Cold War to demonstrate to the world our peaceful use of space for all mankind, etc, etc.  Thus, they don't develop State Secrets.

(Military rockets that launch from Cape Canaveral launch from *Cape Canaveral Air Force Station*, which is next door to *Kennedy Space Center*.)

From the law authorizing NASA:

https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/public_law_111-314-title_51_national_and_commercial_space_programs_dec._18_2010.pdf

> § 20101.  Short title 
>   This  chapter  may  be  cited  as  the  ‘‘National  Aeronautics  and
>   Space Act’’
>
> § 20102.  Congressional declaration of policy and purpose 
>   (a)  DEVOTION OF SPACE ACTIVITIES TO PEACEFUL PURPOSES FOR BENEFIT OF ALL HUMANKIND.— Congress declares that it is the policy of the United States that activities in space should be devoted to peaceful purposes for the benefit of all humankind.
>
> (b)   AERONAUTICAL AND SPACE ACTIVITIES FOR WELFARE AND SECURITY OF UNITED STATES.— Congress  declares that the general welfare  and  security  of  the  United  States  require  that  adequate provision  be  made  for  aeronautical  and  space  activities.  Congress further  declares  that  such  activities  shall  be  the  responsibility  of,  and  shall  be  directed  by,  a  *civilian  agency  exercising  control  over  aeronautical  and  space  activities  sponsored  by  the  United  States*,  **except  that  activities  peculiar  to  or  primarily  associated with  the  development  of  weapons  systems,  military  operations,  or the   defense   of   the   United   States   (including   the   research and development  necessary  to  make  effective  provision  for  the  defense of  the  United  States)  shall  be  the  responsibility  of,  and  shall  be directed  by,  the  Department  of  Defense**;  and  that  determination as  to  which  agency  has  responsibility  for  and  direction  of  any such activity shall be made by the President.

Comment: Various computer technologies (encryption being one in particular) have been on embargo lists because of their potential for military application, even though its critical to civilian use like securing internet sites for purposes like online banking. Technology related to vehicle re-entry could be be used for nuclear warheads.

Comment: @AnthonyX was encryption developed by NASA?  No.

Comment: @AnthonyX quite successful heat shielding for nuclear warheads were developed by both the US and Sovs *loooong* before the 1970s.

Comment: Much of the information relating to those DOD payloads on the shuttle was classified at the time, including launch times, azimuths, etc, which information was certainly developed by NASA flight design based on customer requirements.  As were the flight plans, crew training plans, and other mission related documentation. Some of that information is still classified.

Comment: @OrganicMarble that has nothing to do with whether or not NASA is a civilian agency?

Comment: It demonstrates that they do, or did, develop "state secrets".

Comment: This suggests that NASA should not be encumbered by ITAR, which is clearly not the case.